# Change event blocks other event from triggering

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm developing an app in SAP Fiori with form in it.

Input value change triggers event (change borrowed from sap.m.InputBase so event is triggered on focus change or by enter key press). Event provides user some info. There is also button that sends data to backend.
But there is a case when user changes input value and clicks send button without pressing enter nor changing focus before action.
What happens is change event is triggered but send event is blocked and not triggered at all. User clicks save again and now send event is triggered twice (which make duplicates).

Here's the demo of problem I'm facing:
`jsfiddle:`
https://jsfiddle.net/o2zLa534/1/

I expect that input change event will be triggered and:
1) nothing will happend and after clicking send only one send event will be triggered or
2) send event will be triggered right after change event has been complited.

I know what the problem is but I cannot find a way out.
Thanks for help.

Comment: (commented) 

Which browser were you testing in, @Artkiller? When I run your fiddle in Firefox (60.8.0esr (32-bit)) it works fine.

When I run it in Chrome (76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) the submit event doesn't fire if you change the field value. When you next click the button the event handler is called twice.
In Edge (42.17134.1.0) it's different again! The submit event isn't fired if the input value has been changed. When you press the button again you get the submit event once (not twice, as with Chrome).

Comment: (commented @MikeDoyle) I see exactly the same behaviour in my own test app: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeedoyle/1c2yhtez/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the alerts. 
If you check your fiddle, modifying to something else, other than using an alert, it'll work normally as expected. This issue is due to the alert usage itself, you should not be using an alert in a ui5 application, no matter what to be honest.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbL9z6rh/6/

```
onInputChange: function(evt){
 evt.getSource().setValue("testing");
},
onSubmit: function(){
 alert("Submitted!");
},
```

If you now put anything into your input, and press the button "Send", you'll see that your input will be changed to "testing", and your submit alert will display.